# Equation of Extremely Simple Problem

Tags: word-problem

I can do the following problem in my head, but I want to understand the equations that the Solutions are suggesting. For some reason, they aren't clicking.

`What is the cost of a donut?`

[image: Cost of Donuts]

**Solution 1**

> If a pizza plus a donut costs \$11.00 and a pizza minus a donut costs \$10.50, then we can combine the two equations together to see that two pizzas plus a donut minus a donut equal \$21.50. Therefore, two pizzas must cost \$11.00 + \$10.50 = \$21.50 one pizza costs \$10.75, and one donut costs \$0.25.

I'm not understanding how they arrived at the conclusion in the last sentence, particularly how they got *one pizza costs \$10.75.*

---

**Solution 2**

> The first equation, "Pizza + Donut = \$11.00" tells us that, together,
>   the cost of one pizza and one donut is \$11.
>
> The second equation, "Pizza - Donut = \$10.50" tells us that the
>   difference between the the cost of one pizza and one donut is \$10.50.
>   More specifically, it tells that a pizza costs \$10.50 more than a
>   donut: "Pizza = \$10.50 + Donut."
>
> If a pizza costs \$10.50 more than a donut, then a pizza and a donut
>   must cost \$10.50 more than two donuts: "Pizza + Donut = $10.50 +
>   Donut + Donut."
>
> Therefore, "\$11.00 = \$10.50 + Donut + Donut."
>
> And we can see that two donuts must cost \$0.50, and one donut must
>   therefore cost \$0.25.

I start to lose track of what they're saying starting here:

> If a pizza costs \$10.50 more than a donut, then a pizza and a donut must cost \$10.50 more than two donuts:

---

I know this is quite a simple problem, and easy to do in my head, but I'd really like to understand the fundamentals of building these equations for harder problems.

Comment: Is it not just division and adding the same thing to both sides?

Answer (score 1):

It helps to use symbols for this. So we have
$ P+D=x$ and $P-D=y$.

Now add and subtract the two equations to get $2P=x+y$ and $2D=x-y$.

Finally divide both sides of each equation by $2$.